# MapBox clustering distance

Tags: ios, distance, markerclusterer, mapbox

I have a MapBox map in my ios-app. Some markers have nearly the same coordinates so i try to cluster them. But now there are to many markers clustered.
Is it possible to reduce the distance between the markers for getting clustered?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), then yes, though you have to edit the source to `RMMapView.m` (it is open source). Look for `clusterAreaSize`.

Comment: I find this:     
    mapView.clusterAreaSize = CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5);
But I want a really small area like (0.0000001, 0.0000001).
But I can not see any a difference between 0.0001 and 0.000000001.
Is there a minimum-clustering?

Another question: I have some different annotations like weatherstationpoints, waypoints, points of interest... . Is it possible to cluster just one or two annotation types ?

Comment: It's possible to selectively cluster with the `-[RMAnnotation clusteringEnabled]` API.